# video stream store in buffer (locally) in as3

Tags: apache-flex, red5, actionscript-3, red5-recorder

I am recording video using Red 5 and action-script, but some time red 5 flex connection close due to some network problem. I Want to store live video stream in buffer (locally, not more than 3 minute), if my red 5 connection close/fail/lost. It is possible to store video locally?